# What does this line of php do?

Tags: php

Namely the href snippet of

```
echo "<tr><td align=center>
    <a href=\edit.php?id=$id&name=$name&email=$email&password=$password\">$id</a></td>
    <td>$name</td><td>$email</td><td>$password</td></tr>";
```

I don't know whether there needs to be a `\"` character before `edit.php`.

Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: Yes it needs \" before edit.php

Comment: On a different note, are you aware that your putting the user's password on GET parameter? I suggest to not do that.

Comment: php variables between " " quotes will be automatically replaced by PHP parser, so this will work as expected, just put \" before edit.php to avoid getting closed " quote before edit.php

Comment: `email=$email&password=$password` looks like a good start.

Comment: @AmirRaminfar: Yes. I won't do that in the real project. I just copied and pasted from some video tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a long string of variables intermixed with regular text. This will be evaluated and the variables will be replaced with their text values. And yes, you *will* need to insert an  escaped double quote just after your `href=\`.

Rather than have this complicated string, I'd do something like this instead:

```
$qVars = array(
  "id" => $id,
  "name" => $name,
  "email" => $email,
  "password" => $password /* really? */
);

$qString = http_build_query( $qVars );

echo "<tr>
        <td><a href='edit.php?{$qString}'>{$id}</a></td>
        <td>{$name}</td>
        <td>{$email}</td>
        <td>{$password}</t>
      </tr>";
```

`http_build_query` does require PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to echo "output" some HTML representing a row of a table.

```
<tr> = table row
<td> = table cell
```

The row will therefore consist of 3 cells the first being a hyperlink to a password editing page. It looks like the href is missing an escaped quote but whether your address is supposed to be relative i.e.

```
<a href=\"edit.php?....
```

or absolute

```
<a href=\"\edit.php?....
```

only you would know.